# Is there a way to detect when a QT QRunnable object is done?

Tags: multithreading, qt, threadpool

Is there a way to detect when a QT QRunnable object is done? (Other than manually creating some signalling event at the end of the run() method.)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use QtConcurrent to run the runnable and use a QFuture to wait for finished.

```
#include <QtConcurrentRun>

class MyRunnable : public Runnable{
  void run();
}
```

in order to run and wait for it you can do the following

```
//create a new MyRunnable to use
MyRunnable instance;

//run the instance asynchronously
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&instance, &MyRunnable::run);

//wait for the instance completion
future.waitForFinished();
```

Qtconcurrent::run will start a new thread to execute method run() on instance and immediately returns a QFuture that tracks instance progress.

Notice however that using this solution you are responsable to keep instance in memory during the execution.

Comment: I think QtConcurrent::run doesn't actually use QRunnable... In your example you derive from class Runnable (QRunnable?) - but I suppose it would work without deriving from any class?

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to keep the example as close as possible to the request. You are right of course: myRunnable might be any class.

Answer (score 4):

There might be, or you might have to go a slight bit higher-level.  The [`QFuture`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfuture.html) and [`QFutureWatcher`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfuturewatcher.html) classes are designed to work with Qt's [Concurrent framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-qtconcurrent.html), and the `QFutureWatcher` class [has a signal](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfuturewatcher.html#finished) when the item it is watching has finished.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? How should I associate the QRunnable with a QFuture? Or are you suggesting not to use QRunnable?

Answer (score 4):

You can add your own `SIGNAL` which gets emitted as the last thing that your `run()` method does. Then simply connect it to coreesponding `SLOT` right before calling `connect(...);`

Comment: Note that you need to inherit your class from both QRunnable and QObject in order to do that.

Comment: You can also directly call slots using QMetaObject::invokeMethod(). If you use Qt::QueuedConnection you can safely call slots in the context of another thread.